# How to write the following code in jmeter with webdriver sampler plugin?

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to write the following two scenarios in WDS(Web Driver Sampler). Please help.

//Scenario - 1

```
webelement table = driver.findelement(By.id("u_0_n"));
List <webElement> tr = table.findElements(By.tagname("tr");
```

//Scenario - 2

```
Select drop2 =new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("month")));
drop2.selectByIndex(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

"**To wait until xpath/ID displayed**"

```
wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("//*[@id='forwardButton']")))
```

"**To click on element.**"
1st

```
var clcikbuttons = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.tagname("//*[@id='forwardButton']"))
clcikbuttons .click();
```

2nd

```
var clcikbuttons = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//*[@id='forwardButton']"))
clcikbuttons .click();
```

**2nd scenario use index**

```
var aghrstgrptxt = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("(//li[contains(@id, 'groupRow')])[1]"))
aghrstgrptxt .click();
```